# Best methods for gaining insights (drivers in my data) searching for patterns

Tags: r, modeling

I want to analyze website data (e.g. every event that a customer took on our website, is captured in binary data (Yes/No).

The target is if a visitor bought something on our web shop.

```
Target Event_1  Event_2 Event_3 Event_4 Event_5 Event_6 Event_7 Event_N
 1      1          0       0      0       1       0      1        0
 0      1          0       0      1       1       0      1        1
 1      0          0       0      0       1       0      1        0
```

In my real data, I have +/- 900 columns (variables representing an event, just like: "Played a video on the Site" 1=YES, 0=NO) and around the 2 million rows (visitors).

**What is the best approach to get INSIGHTS in the data?**

**First**, I tried a RandomForest (traint on predicting the target, and tried to unlock it by looking at Variables importance and 'unlocking the RF'. The thing is, that it is very hard to interpret the results.

**Therefore**, I tried more statistical models, such as a Linear Model (lm()). But as you might know, with so many columns, I had some troubles with multicollinearity. **To deal with the multicollinearity**, I tried to build an Elastic Net (for binary classification). But I am not sure if this is the right approach.

This leads that I am stuck. **How can I get insights in such a big data set, with many, many features and many, many rows?** And I am **not really interested in predicting** (since the RF is doing that well), but I am more interested in the drivers, why are people buying stuff on my website (or why are they not buying stuff).

Summarized: 
What is the best approach for explaining my Target (Y) with my predictors (X)?

Comment: I think you are on the right track here, what you are really looking for are feature selection algorithms that will tell you which variables are important in predicting your target.  The importance measures (mean decrease accuracy and mean decrease GINI) in RF will do this for you.  Regularized regression such as elastic net will also do this by shrinking the coefficients of unimportant features to 0.

Comment: @astel: Thanks for your reply. But these methods will not help me with making concrete business actions. I want to have something similar as the coefficients from a regression model (e.g. “if you increase X2 with 1, then the probability that a visitor will buy something will increase with ....%”. Do you have some advice, tips or tricks for me, @astel? Really appreciated!